# Is this the slope of the function?

Tags: calculus, functions

In some notes that I am reading there is the following:

[image]

$$f(A)=c_1 \\ f(B)=c_2 \\ f'(x)=\lambda \\ f(x)=\mu x+\nu \Rightarrow f'(x)=\mu$$ 
What exactly does the relations $f'(x)=\lambda$ and $f(x)=\mu x+\nu \Rightarrow f'(x)=\mu$ in this case? The slope of the function at the point $x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, $f'(x_0) = \lambda$ is the slope of the line tangent to $y = f(x)$ at the point $(x_0, y_0)$.  Similarly, $f'(x_1) = \mu$ is the slope of the line tangent to $y = f(x)$ at the point $(x_1, y_1)$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-) Could you take a look also at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453811/formula-of-arc-length Do you maybe have an idea?

Comment: Is $f(x)=\mu x+\nu$ the tangent line at the point $(x_1, y_1)$ ? Or what does this represent?

Comment: You should specify that further via the equation $y_1 = f(x_1) = {\mu}{x_1} + \nu$.  Then since $f'(x_1) = \mu$, the statement follows.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-)